# Django Rest Framework returns {'detail': 'Not found.'} when tested although it is showing Data in URL

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I have the following django project with the following views.py:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
def getItem(request, **kwargs):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=request.user)
    items=Item.objects.filter(user=user)
    serializer = ItemSerializer(items, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Here is the serializer.py

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.CharField(source="user.username", read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model= Workout
        fields = '__all__'
```

Here is the outcome in the Django Rest Framework URL:

```
Get Workout
GET /api/Shiko/items/
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "user": "Shiko",
        "active": false,
        "name": "Item 1",
        "slug": null
    }
]
```

Test using Jupyter to check for data availablity:

```
import requests

data = requests.get(URL)
json_data = data.json()
print (json_data)
```

**My question:**

What could be wrong in my settings that needs changed to return valid data in my test code knowing that there is data in Json but returning not found when testing.

Also I have used `IsAuthenticated` which returned `{'detail': 'Authentication credentials were not provided.'}` which means that the test code is valid.

What am I doing wrong and how should I fix?

Comment: You're trying to retrieve an `Item` object from the database with respect to the *"logged-in user"*. Unfortunately, you're using `AllowAny` permission class, But, if you need to get anything related to the logged-in user, you must've used the `IsAuthenticated` class (or similar)

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your logic, because you are using `get_object_or_404` function to try to get the actually user from request.user, but your view uses AllowAny, so in some cases this field could be None, and your response could 404.

Maybe you need get to auth some user in your Jupyter "Testing Code"?

But I think is a bad idea testing code with Jupyter, because that is not a testing case or something else.

You can to try use Pytest https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.2.x/, coverage https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/6.5.0/ to test your code, is very easy and beatuful!